# i can't create feed at amazon selling api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to change the image of a product using the amazon selling-partner api, but I'm getting an error in the createFeed stage!

About the development environment

Laravel Framework 8.49.1
pkg  jlevers/selling-partner-api : 3.1

I'm Japanese, so there may be some strange English in the text. I'm sorry.

I want to use sp api's create feed to change the images of my registered products on Amazon, but an error occurs at the create feed stage.

However, an error occurs at the create feed stage. The create document before the create feed does not generate an error, and returns 200.

The code itself is almost entirely taken from jlevers/selling-partner-api, and the instructions follow the official github guide.
I'm Japanese, so there may be some strange English in the text.

The Error Content

```
[400] {"errors": [{"code": "InvalidInput","message": "Invalid request parameters","details": ""}]
```

In addition to this api, I also use report api, which works without any particular error, so I don't think it's an error with required parameters such as client ID, but it's not clearly stated in the error message what parameters are wrong, and I've been stuck here for two days and I'm going crazy...

I tried searching in English, Japanese, and Chinese, but there were not many people with similar errors, and the issues on github did not resolve the issue, so I could not find out.

I would like to know if anyone can tell me what it is.

code

```
$config = new Configuration([
    "lwaClientId" => config('client_id'),
    "lwaClientSecret" => config('secret_id'),
    "lwaRefreshToken" => config('refresh_token'),
    "awsAccessKeyId" => config('aws_key'),
    "awsSecretAccessKey" => config('aws_secret'),
    "endpoint" => SellingPartnerApi\Endpoint::FE,
]);

$feedType = FeedType::POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA;
$feedsApi = new FeedsApi($config);

// Create feed document
\Log::debug("before create feed document");
$createFeedDocSpec = new Feeds\CreateFeedDocumentSpecification(['content_type' => $feedType['contentType']]);
$feedDocumentInfo = $feedsApi->createFeedDocument($createFeedDocSpec);
$feedDocumentId = $feedDocumentInfo->getFeedDocumentId();

$feedContents = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>****</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>ProductImage</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <ProductImage>
            <SKU>*********</SKU>
            <ImageType>Main</ImageType>
            <ImageLocation>http://***/***.jpg</ImageLocation>
        </ProductImage>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;
$docToUpload = new SellingPartnerApi\Document($feedDocumentInfo, $feedType);
$docToUpload->upload($feedContents);

$body = new Feeds\CreateFeedSpecification([
    'feed_type' => $feedType["name"],
    "marketplace_ids" => ["A1VC38T7YXB528"],
    "input_feed_document_id" => $feedDocumentId,
]);

$apiInstance = new FeedsApi($config);
try {
    $result = $apiInstance->createFeed($body);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
$res = "";
    \Log::debug('Exception when calling SellersApi->getMarketplaceParticipations: '. $e->getMessage());
}
```

Sorry, I couldn't resist posting the code, so I uploaded it to google drive.
The link above is to the google drive.

Finally
I would like to know if there is any information that I am missing to solve this problem so that I can correct it immediately.

Links
[jlevers/selling-partner-api](https://github.com/jlevers/selling-partner-api)
[Official Documents](https://github.com/amzn/amazon-advertising-api-php-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you are still experiencing issues, but this is error is common (albeit confusing) when seller accounts are inactive / deactivated and updating your charge method and waiting 48 hours may do the trick.  Can also call Amazon Seller support to double-check or create a case in the Case Log on seller central.

Comment: Thank you.
I completely forgot that I had thrown this question out there.
I've already solved this problem.
You were right, it was an error that showed up because my Amazon account was inactive.
I contacted Amazon and activated my account and that solved it!
thx

Comment: so, what could be the possible issue in seller central account which could cause this error, could it be missing identity info?